# Creating a MongoDB collection for each Kafka topic automatically in MongoDB Kafka Sink Connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

Is there a way in the MongoDB Kafka Sink Connector to create a MongoDB collection for per Kafka topic by defining a pattern or prefix or other way?

Comment: Isn't a collection created by the sink connector already, if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

@OneCricketeer already pointed out in the comments that the sink connector creates topics already. If you don't specify a value for `collection` in the configuration, the default setting is the topic name. To match every topic that your producers write to, you can use `"topics.regex": ".*"`. It's easy to overlook in the mongodb [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/sink-connector/configuration-properties/mongodb-namespace/)